# Android - possibility to select List or Grid

Tags: android, listview, gridview, adapter

As I write in the title, I would like to study the way through you can choose ListView or GridView.
I googled, but I have not found enough.

In my case, I have an **custom Adapter for ListView**, if I want to implement also an GridView, how do you that?

I appreciate any resources, also if you know tutorials! Thanks :)

Comment: Try recyclerview https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I would put both in the same layout, alternating the visibility

Comment: Thanks Sanjeet.
@Bkackbelt, how?

Comment: You shouldn't have two layouts with different visibilities. That's only mess up your code and brings a lot of duplicated logic. Read my answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve these different views without a lot of duplicated logic you should consider to use a **RecyclerView** and change dynamicly  it's **LayoutManager** to what your user wants.

Comment: Hi, but I should rewrite the adapter?

Comment: You should write a adapter with extends from RecyclerView.Adapter and use this adapter for both views by setting a different LayoutManager object to your RecyclerView object.

Comment: Ok, then if I I want the list:
LinearLayoutManager;
While, if I want the grid:
GridLayoutManager, right?
By implementhing this through a clickListener?

Comment: That's ist. One XML Element. One adapter but different views.

Comment: An activitymain.xml and one xml for CardView and one for ListView, right?

Comment: You only need the RecyclerView inside your Activity-main.xml and a layout xml for a specific items inside the list or row

Comment: Ok, just change the Layout Manager(Grid or Linear).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same custom adapter for a GridView and also for a ListView.
CustomAdapter:

```
package com.example.nadiaakter.gridviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ImageView imageView;
    Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        }else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
    Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
android:id="@+id/gvImage"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
```

/>

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nadiaakter.gridviewexample;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    GridView gridView;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvImage);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }   

}
```

Note:It was the GridView example. The ListView example (same CustomAdapter )is as below:

xml

```
<ListView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/lvImage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
    />
```

Again the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nadiaakter.gridviewexample;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView listView;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvImage);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```